# realloc func breaks the app

Tags: c, memory-management, realloc

the app breaks in the realloc func and I don't know why... someone?
here is the line that the code breaks in it:
        *(pointerToStr + i) = realloc( *(pointerToStr + i), sizeof( char ) * lengthOfStr );

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEGIT_LENGTH 30
struct friend{
    unsigned const int stringLen;
    char* name;
}ori;
int main(void)
{
    unsigned int friendsNum = 0;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    unsigned int lengthOfStr = 0;
    char* pointerToStr = NULL;
    printf( "Please enter the amount of friends u have: \n\n \t" );
    scanf( "%d", &friendsNum );
    struct friend *friends = malloc( sizeof( struct friend ) * friendsNum );// struct array
    for (i = 0; i < friendsNum; i++)
    {

        (pointerToStr) = (char*)malloc( sizeof( char ) * MAX_LEGIT_LENGTH );
        printf( "Please enter the name of ur friend:\n" );
        getchar();
        fgets( (pointerToStr + i), 20, stdin );
        ((pointerToStr + i))[strcspn( (pointerToStr + i), "\n" )] = '\0';
        lengthOfStr = strlen( (pointerToStr + i) + 1 );
        *(pointerToStr + i) = realloc( *(pointerToStr + i), sizeof( char ) * lengthOfStr );
    }
```

Comment: `*(pointerToStr + i)` is not a pointer that was returned by `malloc`, so you can't call `realloc` on it.

Comment: I was starting to post an answer, but I realized that I can't figure out what you're trying to do with that loop, so I can't show you how to do it correctly. It looks like you may intend to have an array of strings instead of a single string. But why don't you use the `friends` array?

Comment: because im still wrtiting the code, it not finished yet..

Comment: `lengthOfStr = strlen( (pointerToStr + i) + 1 );` should be `lengthOfStr = strlen(pointerToStr + i) + 1;`

Comment: and:
in line 26 (with the malloc) why i cant write:
 
(pointerToStr + i) = (char*)malloc( sizeof( char ) * MAX_LEGIT_LENGTH );

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but instead of `*(pointerToStr + i)` it's almost always preferable to write `pointerToStr[i]`.

Comment: @OriVAgmon What does it mean to assign something to the result of adding two things? You can't write `intvar + 3 = 5;`, can you?

Answer (score 1):

`*(pointerToStr + i)`, or more concisely, `pointerToStr[i]` is not returned by `malloc`. Thus, `realloc` will not accept it. The normal way that blocks are resized is like this

```
const size_t INITALLOC = 16;   /* #chars to alloc initially */
const size_t ALLOCSTEP =  8;   /* #chars to realloc by */

char *blk = malloc(INITALLOC);
size_t nalloced = INITALLOC;   /* #chars alloced */
size_t n = 0;                  /* #chars used */
size_t i;

for (i = 0; /* some condition */; ++i) {
    /* fill up the block */

    /* if array is full */
    if (n == nalloced)
        blk = realloc(blk, nalloced += ALLOCSTEP);
}

/* use blk */

/* return blk to the heap */
free(blk);
```

The problem here, though, is that if `realloc` fails (returns `NULL`), then all data in the block is lost. No error checking is performed, because `malloc` and `realloc` can return NULL if the heap is exhausted.